# Orecle SQL Developer : why do i get end statement unknown command error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Day_Name(P_DAY DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN(TO_CHAR(P_DAY,'DAY'));
END;
```

ı cant understands where is the problem.
ı take "END
Error report -
Unknown Command" error

Comment: Add a `/` on a new line afterwards. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3e2ea6f1b2b9d6e0b01a16689d7a4aa3)

Comment: Do you have the word `END` selected/highlighted when you run the statement or script? Or perhaps a stray `END` later in the script?

Comment: may be you are not compiling the function and executing it by pressing ctrl+enter ? Try  running it as script and this should work.